# ggplot2 and qvalue error: Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type qvalue

Tags: r, ggplot2, q-value

I have a data frame consisting of 1893 p-values that I convert to qvalues using the R package `qvalue`:

```
pvals <- read.table("p_values.csv",header=T,sep=",",dec=".")
```

The qvalue manual states you can directly plot (using the qplot function) the output of the qvalue function by:

```
qobj <- qvalue(pvals)
qplot(qobj)
```

However this results instead in an error:

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type qvalue.
>   Defaulting to continuous Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]],
>   optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :    cannot
>   coerce class ""qvalue"" to a data.frame

Anyone have an idea how to fix this and make `qplot` plot the output of the `qvalue` function?

Comment: You should check the class of `qobj`. If its class is not compatible with `qplot`, you need to modify `qobj` to fit `qplot` requirements.